# RadEditor in DNN 6.x - Nested bullet syntax is incorrect

Tags: dotnetnuke-6, radeditor, bulletedlist

Normally, creating nested bullet lists is easy with RadEditor. I create one long bullet list, then select the subpart of the list that I want to make into a sub-list, hit the indent button and I'm good.

But in DNN 6.x, when I do this, it inserts the sub-list between closed li elements, rather than as a child of one of the li elements.

**Expected Syntax:**

```
 <ul>
 <li>Item one</li>
 <li>Item two
      <ul>
          <li>sub one</li>
          <li>sub two</li>
      </ul
 </li>
 <li>Item three</li>
 </ul>
```

**Syntax I am Getting:**

```
 <ul>
 <li>Item one</li>
 <li>Item two</li>

      <ul>
          <li>sub one</li>
          <li>sub two</li>
      </ul

 <li>Item three</li>
 </ul>
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how I can avoid it?